# render records in databales

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am rendering the data created and edited in a js.erb to a datatable, the problem is that when making use of pagination, such data disappears. this my index:

```
 <table id="superior" class="display"><!--el id activos es de datatables referenciado en activos.coffe y display class es una clase de datatables-->
  <thead>

    <tr><!--active es para sombrear la fila-->
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Modelo</th>
      <th>FechaAlta</th>
      <th>Serie</th>
      <th>CB</th>
      <th>Imagen</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody id="container_activos">
      <%= render @activos %><!--carga todos los activos-->
</tbody>


</table>
```

my partial _activo.html.erb

```
<tr id="activo_<%= activo.id %>">
    <td><%= activo.IdActivos %>

</td>
    <td><%= activo.Descripcion %></td>
    <td><%= activo.Modelo%> </td>
    <td><%= activo.Fecha%>></td>
    <td><%= activo.Serie %></td>
    <td><%= activo.CB %></td>
    <td id="producto-imagen" >
        <%= image_tag activo.cover.url(:minithumb) %>
    </td>
    <td><%= activo.Status %>
    </td>
    <td>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myupdateactivo_<%= activo.id %>">
        Editar
      </button>

    </td>

<td>
</td>
</tr>
```

my create.js.erb:

```
$("#mynewactivo").modal('hide');

  $("#container_activos").prepend('<%= j render @activo %>'); //Prepend before append
  $("#activo_<%= @activo.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);


$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/flash' , :locals => { :flash => flash }).html_safe %>");

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#notice').fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).create();
  })
}, 1500);
```

my update.js.erb:

```
$("#myupdateactivo_<%= @activo.id %>").modal('hide');
$("#mynewactivoenvase").modal('show');

$("#activo_<%= @activo.id %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $(".child").remove();
  $("#container_activos").prepend('<%= j render @activo %>');

});
$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/flash' , :locals => { :flash => flash }).html_safe %>");

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#notice').fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).create();
  })
}, 1500);
```